# How to update X25-E SSD firmware in PowerEdge 2900 with PERC 5/i

Tags: raid, ssd, dell-poweredge

How to update the X25-E SSD firmware in a Dell PowerEdge 2900 with aPERC 5/i RAID controller?  In other words, how to make the two SSD's visible to a firmware boot disk as such, when the RAID controller is presenting them as one RAID 1 volume?

Answer (score 2):

I updated the X25-E firmware by temporarily removing each SSD from its drive carrier and Icy Dock adapter, and connecting it as follows:

Data - connect the data interface of the SSD to the onboard SATA-A port of the PE2900 system board using a standard SATA data cable.

Power - connect a Molex-to SATA power cable from a spare Molex connector to the power interface of the SSD.

In BIOS, enable onboard SATA and enable the SATA-A port.  Boot to the boot-CD containing the Intel firmware updater.

After the update completes, restore the orignal Icy-Dock, drive carrier, backplane configuration and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Download and use the Dell Server Updates Utility (SUU).

http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?releaseid=R236931

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have 500 of these machines, I'd say the easiest solution is probably to pull the drives out and install them in the nearest convenient desktop machine for updating.

Comment: Agreed. Even if the OP succeeded in loading a driver for the RAID controller on a boot disk, it could easily still not work. The firmware update programs often rely on ATA command pass-through, and other less used corner areas of the ATA / AHCI interfaces, which many controllers / drivers don't implement correctly.